# I am having issue in prima, whenever i run prisma generate i alway get an error

Tags: database, mongodb, backend, node-modules, prisma

Error:  EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Bright-Ewuru\Desktop\full stack real estate\server\node_modules.prisma\client\query_engine-windows.dll.node'.

This the error i get when running npx prisma generate with working with react, mongodb and express

I was expecting no error after i run npx prisma generate, i also trying restarting my server but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

delete the file  'C:\Users\Bright-Ewuru\Desktop\full stack real estate\server\node_modules.prisma\client\query_engine-windows.dll.node'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).